# Android Room Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

i am using Hilt and Coroutine Worker to request API and after fetching data i wanna upsert it to my room repositry , the problem here is even i used `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` it trow this error:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
> lock the UI for a long period of time.

by the way i don't wanna enable **allowMainThreadQueries()** on my room and still wanna update my repo in IO Thread

and my worker code:

```
@HiltWorker
class CheckForNewProfilePhotos @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val usersAPI: UsersAPI,
    private val rUserRepository: RUserRepository
) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val usersIdsToFetch = inputData.getLongArray("usersIdsToFetch")

            val response = usersIdsToFetch?.let {
                usersAPI.getMultipleUsers(
                    GetMultipleUsers(it.toList())
                )
            }

            response?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<User>> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<User>>,
                    response: Response<List<User>>
                ) {

                    response.body()?.let {
                        rUserRepository.upsert(it.toMutableList())
                        //                      conversationRepository.updateUserData(it)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<User>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Result.retry()
                }
            })

            return@withContext Result.success()
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: @wtz it can't be done because `onResponse` is not a `suspend` function. `withContext` can only be called from a `suspend` function or a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Callback<List<User>>` to a `suspend` function using `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` builder functions and then after calling it and getting a result body insert data to the DB:

```
private suspend fun makeRequest() = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val usersIdsToFetch = inputData.getLongArray("usersIdsToFetch")

    val response = usersIdsToFetch?.let {
        usersAPI.getMultipleUsers(GetMultipleUsers(it.toList()))
    } 

    response?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<User>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<User>>,
                response: Response<List<User>>
            ) {
                continuation.resume(response.body()) // resumes suspended coroutine
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<User>>, t: Throwable) {
                Result.retry()
                continuation.resume(null) // or continuation.resumeWithException(t) if you want to handle Exceptions
            }
    })
}

override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val body = makeRequest()
        return@withContext if (body != null) {
            rUserRepository.upsert(it.toMutableList())
            // conversationRepository.updateUserData(it)
            Result.success()
        } else {
            Result.retry()
        }
    }
}
```